# curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received

Tags: networking, curl

I'm installing meteor through curl, But getting this error:

```
curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Installation failed.
```

Now I don't know how to resolve this issue. Any help will be appriciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding the `-k`/`--insecure` option to `curl` solved the issue:

```
curl -k [URL...]
```

This works by allowing the connection to proceed even if the SSL certificate cannot be validated. This helps get around some problems, including server misconfiguration, but you should be aware that you may not be able to trust the data you download. As [the `curl` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/curl.1.html) says:

> **-k, --insecure**
>
> (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to  perform  "insecure" SSL
>   connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be
>   made secure by using the CA certificate  bundle  installed by 
>   default. This  makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless
>   *-k, --insecure* is used.
>
> See this online resource for further details:
>   http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html